# Is this a bug in the R parser or Working as Designed

Tags: r, parsing

```
f <- function(x) {
  e <- new.env(parent = emptyenv())
  e$x <- x

  b <- e$

  #This is a test
  a <- 'Hi'
  print(a)
}
```

Note that the member of e was not specified on the b <- e$ line

Under R GUI 3.4.2.0 this prints "1 2 3".

Under RStudio this reports "Error in print(a) : object 'a' not found"

Patient: Doctor! Doctor! It hurts when I do this!

Doctor: Well, then don't do it.

Comment: Cannot reproduce with R-3.3.3 nor R-3.4.1, in Rgui, emacs/ess, or RStudio (all win10). Perhaps it's something within your environment?

Comment: Presumably it prints "1 2 3" in an environment in which there is a global `a` with value `1 2 3`. I don't know much about R but a language in which setting a variable to `'Hi'` caused it to be printed as `1 2 3` would be esoteric, to say the least, so I presume the `a` is being interpreted as part of `e$a`, in spite of the intervening newlines and comment.

Comment: I can't reproduce this either, R 3.4.1 in RStudio.